# Strange encoding issue in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, encoding, character-encoding

hope someone could help in this

I have a database containing text in English and German, I am using php with Postgres database, querying text in English works fine, but when the query string contains any German letter I get empty result.

For example:

```
select field from Table where field ilike '%software%'
```

returns results as expected

```
select field from Table where field ilike '%bersetzung%'
```

returns results as expected

```
select field from Table where field ilike '%Übersetzung%'
```

returns empty set

show client_encoding returns UNICODE, even running the above queries in pgadmin returns empty set when there is any German letter in the query string.

The database encoding is UTF-8

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use case insensitive pattern matching with PostgreSQL and Umlauts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104769/how-to-use-case-insensitive-pattern-matching-with-postgresql-and-umlauts)

Comment: Its not a pattern related question, the problem is with the encoding, I also have up to date pg server, I saw your suggested question before asking here and its not even similar issue.

Comment: what's the value in the field and the value of `lc_ctype` for this database?

Comment: the field type is text, the value is German text, lc_ctype=en_US, am I supposed to change that? if yes to which?

Comment: I don't know, `en_US` is not valid for me. `en_US.UTF-8` is valid and seems aware that `lower('Ü')='ü'`. Although strictly speaking it depends on the locale implementation of your operating system.

Comment: Its not case issue, I am searching the exact string with LIKE and still no result. I also added de_DE UTF-8 to my operating system locale and it didn't solve the problem. its really strange.

Comment: Turn query logging on and just check you are sending the characters you expect.

Comment: Possibly you've not setup proper `LC_CTYPE` when database was created. It may be different from your default system locale. You can see locale settings for each database in `psql` when typing `\l`.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has a number of oddities in how it depends on system behavior.  This is one.  In general, localization support is dependent on system libraries and system behavior.  This is true both for things like upper/lowercase and for things like collation.

It doesn't look like you can create the database's localization settings after database setup.  You may need to back up the database, re-create it with the right localization settings, and reload your data.  That's probably not the answer you were looking for but it is probably the best one.